# Error webpage has expire on IE program asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 form's `A` and `B`.

In form `A` has I have a control like textbox used to input data and has validate data and uses ASP control validation, it has 2 buttons s 
button `Save` to save data in DB, and button `next` to move to form `B`.
you must insert less 1 time  to process form B

But when in form `B`, I click back button on browser IE it has an, error  webpage has expired
if i refresh it dislay form `A` ,but in Firefox, Chrome it's ok.

What happen? Please give me  some direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are actually trying to achieve here you have submitted a form and then pressed back, meaning you want to submit a new form.
You should be handling the back command inside your form not relying on the browser's button .

You should also try to be clearer in questions to make it easier for people to answer you.